# split string to array where length is not fixed (not bash)

Tags: linux, shell

How is it possible to split a string to an array?

```
#!/bin/sh
```

eg.

```
str="field 1,field 2,field 3,field 4"
```

The length of the arrays is various

Have found alot of solutions but they only works in bash

## update

This only works if the length of the array has 4 values, but what if it has 10 values?

The for loop doesn't seem to work

```
arr=$(echo "field 1,field 2,field 3,field 4" | awk '{split($0,a,","); print a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]}');

for value in ${arr[@]}
do
    echo "$value\n"
done
```

Comment: by what separator do you want to split string? `,` or ` `

Comment: The plain POSIX shell does not support arrays at all. You need to use a shell (`bash`, `zsh`, probably others) that does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the split into variables in dash (that doesn't support arrays) use:

```
string="field 1,field 2,field 3,field 4"
IFS=","
set -- $string
for val
do
  echo "$val"
done
```

Comment: how can you assign all values to a variable? and what if the array is longer than 4 values?

Comment: the array returned by awk will be as long as there are fields in the input. I'm not sure what you mean about assigning the values to a variable

Comment: have updated the question.. in you exampe you only print up to 4 values, but what if the array has 10 values? The for loop doesn't seem to work either

Comment: so, bash supports arrays, dash doesn't so you are a bit restricted in what you can do. Updating answer.

Comment: thanks.. is there any way to run through each value with a loop?

Comment: You don't need `in "$@"`, it's the default

Answer (score 0):

In bash you can do this:

```
str="field 1,field 2,field 3,field 4"
IFS=, array=($str)
```

`IFS` is the input field separator.

Zsh is much more elegant

```
array=${(s:,:)str}
```

You can even do it directly

```
% for i in "${(s:,:)str[@]}"; do echo $i; done
field 1
field 2
field 3
field 4
```

Comment: Then use the first one

Comment: the first one (first two lines alone) returns an error `test.sh: 4: test.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: @clarkk You aren't using `bash`; your shell does not support arrays.

Comment: Run it as `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`